# How many kids do each of my aunts have?

Tags: logical-deduction

We have got our yearly festival tomorrow. So my two ancient aunts are making these totally cool sweets. I was there to help them and just check our what I found.

> My 1st aunt is really great at cooking while the 2nd is still trying
>   to catch it. Well the amount of sweets they made just proves it.  Both
>   my aunts cooked sweets as much as the square of their children. And
>   the total amount of sweets that both of them made is as the cube of
>   the no. of children my 2nd aunt has.
>
> Given that the whole family, about 30 people would be coming to the
>   get together tomorrow.

So, How many kids do each of my aunts have?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We can set up an equation for a problem like this:

> $x$ is the number of children the first aunt has and $y$ is the number of children the second aunt has. Then the first aunt made $x^2$ sweets and the second $y^2.$ Their total is $x^2+y^2.$
>  Since the total is the cube of $y,$ we can say $x^2+y^2 = y^3.$

Then do some simplification:

> Subtract $y^2$ from both sides to get $x^2 = y^3-y^2.$ Now factor out $y^2$ from the right to get $x^2 = y^2(y-1).$

So what does this tell us?

> Well, the left side is a perfect square, so the right side must also be a perfect square. Since $y^2$ is already a perfect square, we must have $y-1$ also be a perfect square. Given the limitation of having $30$ people, this tells us that $y-1$ equals either $1,$ $4,$ $9,$ $16,$ or $25.$ So $y$ equals one of $2,5,10,17,26.$

But...

> We also must have $x+y \le 30.$ With a little testing, we can see that $y=2$ works as $y^2(y-1) = 2^2 = 4$ so $x=2$ also. $y=5$ also works, as $y^2(y-1) = 25\cdot 4 = 100$ which means $x=10.$ But $y=10$ won't work since $y^2(y-1) = 100\cdot9 = 900.$ This means that $x=30$ but then we'd have more than 30 people at the reunion.

So either....

> They both have $2$ kids or aunt 1 has $10$ kids and aunt 2 has $5$ kids. To check both:
> $2^2+2^2=8$ which is equal to $2^3$ and $10^2 +5^2 = 125$ which is equal to $5^3.$ Given that the first aunt is better at cooking, I'm going to say that the first aunt has $10$ kids and the second $5.$

Answer (score 3):

> Your first aunt has 10 children and your second has 5.

Explanation:

> Your description leads to the equation $x^2+y^2=y^3$ (where $x$ is the number of children of your first aunt and $y$ is the number of children of your second aunt.
> Looking for integer solutions to this, we can see pairs such as $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(2,2)$, $(10,5)$, and $(30,10)$. However, we've been told to expect approximately 30 people. $(10,5)$ means 15 children, plus a number of other family members (a minimum of 18 people including you and the aunts). $(30, 10)$ is a minimum of 43 people, so the former answer is the closest.

Answer (score 2):

They can have

> both 2 children

Because

> both cooked 2^2=4 sweets, making it 8 in total which is the number of children either aunt has, cubed.

But then,

> how does it prove that the 1st aunt it better than the second at cooking I don't know O_o

Comment: Taste of sweets, I guess. :P

Answer (score 2):

I think the right answer is:

> The 1st Aunt cooked 100 sweets because she has 10 children.

The second aunt

> Cooked 25 sweets because she has 5 children.

Finally,

> Total no. Of sweets=125 which is the cube of the number of children of the second aunt.

This also satisfies the other condition:

> 1st Aunt is obviously a better cook because she cooks 4 times as much as the second Aunt. And if we include the children and everything, the total number of people *might* come out to be 30.

Answer (score 1):

They have

> 10 and 5

children, so they made

> 100 and 25 which is 125 (=5^3) sweets.

If we think everybody mentioned here will come, than the next minimum will be too high:

> at 30 and 10 children, 30(aunt 1's children) + 10( aunt 2's children) + 2(aunts) + 1(story teller) = 43 minimum person.